# Regarding PHP autoload/spl_autoload

Tags: php, autoload

I'm curious on how these functions work.

I notice in frameworks like CodeIgniter, you're able to do things like

`Class New_Model extends CI_Model`

Does CI use these autoload functions to facilitate this behavior?

In my current set-up, I have a bunch of includes as well as class instantiations at the top of each file to handle users, forum threads/posts, and other system variables like site name/base url, and so on.  My goal is to only have to include one file that I can use to instantiate classes.

Comment: How about under the hood: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/spl/php_spl.c#464